# Node.js MYSQLparse error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have the following code

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM ?", [req.params.Tables_in_my_db], function(error, rows, fields) {
    if (error)
        throw error;

    //code...

    db.end();
});
```

When I run this code I get the following error

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Copy'' at line 1

However, if I log in the console req.params.Tables_in_my_db, I get the String Copy. How can I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: is the table you're trying to read called `Copy`?

Comment: I'm trying to create a different view for each table in the database. Copy is one of those tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess "?" will only work with values to be substituted, (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name=?), if you want to have a dynamic table, use if statement and concatenate your desired table to the string, then pass that string to the first param of db.query().

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM";
if (req.params.table_code == 1) {
     query += " your_desired_table";
} else if (req.params.table_code == 2) {
     query += " another_desired_table";
} else {
     //return an error here to avoid sql injection, use a code for each of 
     //the table you only want to use
}

db.query(query, ....
```

Comment: I see now, thank you for the help this was exactly what I needed.